# Error management in ASP.NET Core using a BaseController

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous ASP.NET versions I was used to create a BaseController inherited from the other controllers and there intercepting the general error and logging each error with a simple logging method and passing the ***ExceptionContext filterContext***.

Should I do the same in ASP.NET 5?

I see in file *Startup.cs* that there is a *if*/*else* statement that basically separate the debug/live condition, with line

```
app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");
```

for a production application.

How am I supposed to hook in the process and log the errors?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Handling and logging errors in ASP.NET 5 involves a few elements.

To handle the error in a production scenario and show an error page, the `app.UseExceptionHandler()` method is the way to go. The Diagnostics repository on the ASP.NET GitHub organisation includes [a sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/samples/ExceptionHandlerSample) that shows this. For development-time scenarios where you want to see a full stack trace and other diagnostic information, use `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` as seen in [this sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/samples/DeveloperExceptionPageSample).

If the application is using ASP.NET MVC 6, then there is an MVC-specific way of handling errors, much as there was in earlier versions of ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET MVC 6, a filter (or the Controller itself, which is also a filter) can handle/override the `OnActionExecuted` method and inspect the `ActionExecutedContext` parameter to attempt to handle the error.

When it comes to logging, there's a new logging infrastructure in ASP.NET 5 that reports a great deal of information to any registered `ILogger`. The default project templates in Visual Studio 2015 register some loggers that log errors (and other data) to the console and the Visual Studio debug output window. However, when running in IIS or IIS Express there is no console window (yet!). But if you run from the command line (using `dnx web`) then you'll see the error. Or, of course, you can register a different logger that writes to a log file or database and see the logs there.

To register a custom `ILogger` in a web app:

1. Write a logger that implements the `ILogger` interface. See the [DNX implementations](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src) for how to do this.
2. Add a parameter of type `ILoggerFactory` to your app's `Startup` class's `Configure` method.
3. In the `Configure` method call `loggerFactory.AddProvider(<some provider>)` and pass in an instance of your logger.

Comment: Thanks, about "register a different logger that writes to a database " do you have a code sample? I would like to call a method or in this case register a logger that write the error message and details to an azure table storage.

Comment: @Eilon The `app.UserErrorHandler()` mechanism doesn't seem to allow me to handle 404 errors.  Any guidance on how to do that?

Comment: @ggovan thanks, I just updated the post with updated info.

Comment: @Light Examples are starting to pop up. Check out https://github.com/aspnet/Logging#providers and https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging for an example on how to log messages to an external API (would be similar for table storage using the .NET client).